# extended permissions etc on facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

I want to pass two parameters to the array `$params` which based on the function `getLoginUrl`, btw I'm using php sdk 3.0.1.

That what I wrote:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                                          'req_perms' => 'publish_stream',
                                          'next' => 'my next url',
                                            ));
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work? I'm pretty sure that the reason is the version of the sdk.. the login is working well but without the extended permissions & next url. any help? thank you.

Comment: You need to tell us in more detail what is happening, when it's happening and what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want that the user will connect to my website. when the user click 'login via facebook' it's really working, but the extended permissions don't appear. (just 'Access my basic information')

Comment: I solved the problem.. `req_perms` is called `scope`, and `next` now called `redirect_uri`.

Answer (score 1):

While you answered yourself in the comments, I will extend the answer. In [21 May](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/), Facebook announced the upgrade of the PHP-SDK which is a major upgrade that would break your code!

So the best way to check the new way the SDK works is by accessing the [example](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) page provided. Now for your case this doesn't provide much of information, so you should be looking in the `base_facebook.php` and indeed you'll find (line 449):

```
/**
* Get a Login URL for use with redirects. By default, full page redirect is
* assumed. If you are using the generated URL with a window.open() call in
* JavaScript, you can pass in display=popup as part of the $params.
*
* The parameters:
* - redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
* - scope: comma separated list of requested extended perms
*
* @param array $params Provide custom parameters
* @return string The URL for the login flow
*/
```

Now the interesting part is the `getLogoutUrl()` method as it's still using the `next` parameter!